# A question on the definition of the logarithmic integral

Tags: calculus, integration, number-theory

The logarithmic integral, which is very important in Number Theory, is defined in the following way:

$$\operatorname{li}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{1}{\ln t}dt\text{.}$$

I don't understand why this equation has two letters or variables ($x$ and $t$). Can someone explain to me what the above equation means? I know what an integral is, but I don't know much calculus.

Thank you!

Comment: For instance, li(5) is the integral of 1/ln t with respect to t, from 1 to 5.

Comment: @Mehta Thank you. And what is $t$?

Comment: I thought the integration range is $1\le t \le x$

Comment: More usually in number theory one uses the close relative $\operatorname{Li}(x)=\int_2^x \frac{1}{\ln t}\,dt$.

Comment: $t$ is just the variable of integration. It's commonly called a dummy variable, since we could just as well have it be $x',y,Z,\aleph$...

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you, and why isn't it $x$?

Comment: Because you're already using $x$ in the limit, so the integration variable should have a different name. Take a look at Mathworld's page on [Dummy Variables](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html) for more discussion.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you, I read it but I still don't get it.

Comment: *All indefinite integrals are definite ones in disguise!* Take for instance $\ln x=\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}x$. Yet, open any serious book of mathematics, and you'll find a similar yet slightly different [expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Definitions): $\displaystyle\int_1^x\frac{dt}t$. Same here: $\text{li}(x)=\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{\ln x}$ is more correctly written as $\displaystyle\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\ln t}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine like the definition of natural logarithm $$ln(x)=\int\limits_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt$$